# Angular Material datepicker expression has changed after it was checked error with min and max

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have angular material datepicker whch has `1. Start date` and `2. End date`. My `end date` depends on `start date`. Would be something similar to this formula :

1. Start date = `2018/09/15`
2. End date = **minimum** `StartDate+1day` , **maximum** `StartDate + 2 months`.

At the start of init i set these values and everything works fine, but then when i change my Start date to to something bigger then 2 months i get this error :

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-valid': 'false'. Current
>   value: 'true'.

**Here is my code :**

```
 startDateChange(event) {
      this.formGroup.get(this.LocationFields.endDate).setValue(moment(event).add(1, 'days').format());
      const afterOneDay = moment(event).add(1, 'days').format();
      this.dropOffDateMax = moment(event).add(2, 'months').format();
      this.dropOffDateMin = afterOneDay;
  }
```

**html :**

```
<input readonly [style.width.px]="width"  (click)="picker.open()" class="form-control datepickerInput {{inputClasses}}"
  [class.is-invalid]="control.invalid" matInput [formControl]="control" [matDatepicker]="picker" [placeholder]="placeholder"
  autocomplete="off" [min]="min" [max]="max" (dateChange)="changeEvent($event); isoString && onInputChange()">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle [disableRipple]="true" matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year"></mat-datepicker>
```

If i remove these lines :

```
  const afterOneDay = moment(event).add(1, 'days').format();
  this.dropOffDateMax = moment(event).add(2, 'months').format();
  this.dropOffDateMin = afterOneDay;
```

**No error then;**

How to change datepicker min and max values without the error ?